# rxjs - handling async errors in finally

Tags: error-handling, promise, rxjs

I'm interested in invoking an async function when I unsubscribe from an observable, however, I'm unable to handle the errors in a synchronized way once unsubscribing, for example I have the following piece of code, and the error isn't catched.

```
const observable = Observable.of(true).finally( async () => {
            throw new Error('what');
        });

        try {
            observable.subscribe().unsubscribe();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('We did not capture this');
        }
```

What are the possible ways of handling async errors in `finally`?

Comment: As of RxJS version 6, errors are never thrown from a `subscribe` call (unless the [deprecated, synchronous error handling](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/config.ts) is explicitly enabled) so the `try`/`catch` will be ineffectual. Also, `finally` will simply ignore the promise your function returns. It doesn't expect one and it's also pointless. Think about it this way: when the callback to `finally` is called, the subscription is finished; there will not be a subscriber to receive your error (via the promise rejection).

Answer (score 1):

I think there're two problems:

1. Calling `unsubscribe()` won't do anything because `of(true)` sends `next` and `complete` notification immediately on subscription. So when you call `unsubscribe()` yourself you're already unsubscribed because of the `complete` notification. Then the actual call `unsubscribe()` won't do anything in this case.
2. When you mark a method as `async` it means you're in fact returning a Promise that is rejected. But `.finally` is expecting a function that it invokes and does nothing with it's return value. When you mark it as `async` it returns a Promise but nobody listens to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the error you will have to remove the async keyword,

```
const observable = Observable.of(true).finally(() => {
            throw new Error('what');
        });
```

with async it will turn it into an asynchronous function and won't be caught. What you are doing now is similar to

```
    try {        
        setTimeout(()=> {throw new Error('what');},10)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('We did not capture this');
    }
```

Throw will excuted in the eventloop instead of the main thread.